# How to get the path of Where MSI file is located from wix source code at run time(Installation time)

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer

I want to Locate path of MSI from WIX Source code when we perform installation. I tried using `$(sys.SOURCEFILEPATH)` which returns what I need (C:\temp\myProj\sample.msi)). But when I copy MSI file to a different folder (D:\temp\sample.msi) and tried to install I am getting the same path as previous(C:\temp\myproj\sample.msi).

Thanks for your answers in advance

Comment: Why would you want to have the location of the msi inside the msi itself exactly? BTW `SOURCEFILEPATH` points to the wxs file, not the msi location.

Comment: in the MSI directory i have exe and batscript file .if i somehow get the msi file location then i can pass the current directory inside the custom action to invoke exe which inturn invoke batscript.

Comment: Then you should have the bat file execute the msi, not the other way around. Having dependencies on files inside your msi is going to give you a lot of headaches later on when trying to uninstall for example.

Comment: I've written deferred custom actions that had OriginalDatabase passed to it via CustomActionData so I could then query the MSI's Binary table to get resources needed for execution of the custom action.  It's pretty common place actually.

Comment: EXE and .BAT files are not a best practice for custom actions.  I'd recommend looking at C#/DTF  custom actions that allow you to pack resources into the CA that will be in the processes working directory at execution.  This is assuming your custom actions are really needed in the first place.  A lot of new WiX users reinvent the wheel with CAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Installer sets the OriginalDatabase property to the path of the installation database used to launch the installation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/originaldatabase

Comment: <Binary Id="ConsoleAppExe" SourceFile="ConsoleAppExe.exe"/><CustomAction Id="ConsoleExe"



                 BinaryKey="ConsoleAppExe"


                 ExeCommand="[OriginalDatabase]"


                 Execute="immediate"


                 Return="check"


                 HideTarget="no"


                 Impersonate="no"
                 
                  
   />

Comment: FYI, Type 2 EXE custom actions have a number of pitfalls.  (Sadly MSFT page that listed them is no longer valid. )  You might want to look into using the Quiet Execution Custom Action. http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html